# cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL' (F:\Pycharm\Python\lib\site-packages\PIL\__init__.py)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pycharm, python-imaging-library

This is the Code that I am trying to run:

```
from tkinter import *

from PIL import ImageTk,Image

root = Tk()

root.title("GUI with Images")

root.iconbitmap('icon.png')

button_quit = Button(root, text=("Exit Program"), command = root.quit)

button_quit.pack()

my_img = ImageTk.PhotoImageTk(Image.open("icon.png"))

my_label = Label(image=my_img)

my_label.pack()



root.mainloop()
```

---

And this is the Error Showing:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File
> "F:\Pycharm\PracticeProjects\PythonPractice\PythonApplication1\images.py",
> line 2, in

```
from PIL import ImageTk,Image
```

> File "F:\Pycharm\Python\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 31,
> in

```
from . import Image
```

> File "F:\Pycharm\Python\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 109, in

```
from . import _imaging as core
```

> ImportError: cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL'
> (F:\Pycharm\Python\lib\site-
>
> packages\PIL_*init*_.py)

Comment: try separate imports

Comment: Try reinstall `Pillow` module inside PyCharm.